# What could cause a java process to get gradually decreasing share of CPU?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I have a very simple java program that prints out 1 million random numbers. In linux, I observed the %CPU that this program takes during its lifespan, it starts off at 98% then gradually decreases to 2%, thus causing the program to be very slow. What are some of the factors that might cause the program to gradually get less CPU time?

I've tried running it with `nice -20` but I still see the same results.

EDIT: running the program with `/usr/bin/time -v` I'm seeing an unusual amount of involuntary context switches (588 voluntary vs 16478 involuntary), which suggests that the OS is letting some other higher priority process run.

Comment: Heavy I/O operations (including memory swapping by the OS), other processes taking up CPU.

Comment: Where does it write to? Maybe it's waiting for IO...

Comment: starting JVM is quite expensive, are you printing those numbers to some file?

Comment: nice -20?  This asks for a lower priority, sounds like you wanted higher.

Comment: @djechlin:  No, that gives the process near-realtime prioritization.

Comment: @djechlin The numbers are reversed from what might be expected, where [-20 is the *least nice* that can be specified](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nice/). (The program is called `nice`, and not `mean` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm actually simply writing to stdout. No file IOs, which is why it is even more puzzling...

Comment: *How* are the numbers printed? To what device (type *and* hardware/medium)? Also, have some sample code? Generally a program doesn't *get* less CPU time (unless it really is being starved), but a program might *use* less CPU (as it waits on events or blocking low-CPU operations).

Comment: All it is doing is (in a for-loop of 1 million iterations) `System.out.println(randomSeed.nextInt())`

Comment: @fo_x86 stdout is still kind of file I/O. Low-level processes use file descriptors to pass stdout information from one  application to another (i.e. from your Java program to your shell).

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I thought stdout had less of an overhead compared to actual file I/O since it doesn't involve the hard-drive.

Comment: @fo_x86 I can't remember to well without going back to my Linux C library code, but parent/child processes use file descriptors to do the stream redirection for this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to two things:

- I/O is expensive, and
- Depending on how you're storing the numbers as you go along, that can have an adverse effect on performance as well.

If you're mainly doing `System.out.println(randInt)` in a loop a million times, then that can get expensive.  I/O isn't one of those things that comes for free, and writing to any output stream costs resources.

Comment: +1. To tie into the CPU dropping, I/O will put the processor into a waiting state while the I/O actually occurs, so your process won't be doing anything while it waits for the I/O to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by profiling via JConsole or VisualVM to see what it's actually doing when it has low CPU %.  As mentioned in comments there's a high chance it's blocking, e.g. waiting for IO (user input, SQL query taking a long time, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is I/O bound - for example waiting for responses from network calls, or disk read/write

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try and balance everything, you should create a queue to hold numbers to print, then have one thread generate them (the producer) and the other read and print them (the consumer). This can easily be done with a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

```
public class PrintQueueExample {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> printQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PrinterThread thread = new PrinterThread();
        thread.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            int toPrint = ...(i) ;
            printQueue.put(Integer.valueOf(toPrint));
        }
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println("Complete");
    }

    private static class PrinterThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Integer toPrint = printQueue.take();
                    System.out.println(toPrint);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interruption comes from main, means processing numbers has stopped
                // Finish remaining numbers and stop thread
                List<Integer> remainingNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                printQueue.drainTo(remainingNumbers);
                for (Integer toPrint : remainingNumbers)
                    System.out.println(toPrint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There may be a few problems with this code, but this is the gist of it.